# Can bash read the "Date Added" of a file/directory?

Tags: bash, osx, stat

With programs like `stat` you see access, modify and change, but with Finder on macOS there is a "Date Added" field. Can I get the "Date Added" for a file or directory displayed in the Terminal, like `stat` can display the Modify date?

Comment: @Christopher Thank you for your answer, but no, for me these are two seperate things. If I move a folder created in 2013 to another directory, the added date in Finder will be 21 February 2019 (today), but your commands return the date when it was originally created in 2013.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some candidates include the following. File times are exposed in metadata, and `mdls` is "**m**eta**d**ata **l**i**s**t". When used with the `-raw` option, output from `mdls` contains fields separated with an NUL character. e.g. as follows.

```
# The creation date which should not change.
mdls -raw -name kMDItemFSCreationDate $filename
```

The `stat` command behaves differently. Results from four versions of two shells using the command, `stat -f $filename`, follow.

1. `/usr/local/bin/zsh`(5.7.1 via Homebrew) produces `stat: missing file descriptor`.
2. `/usr/local/bin/bash` (5.0.2(1) via Homebrew) produces `testing.txt`.
3. `/bin/zsh` (5.3 included with macOS) produces `stat: missing file descriptor`.
4. `/bin/bash` (3.2.57(1) include with macOS produces `testing.txt`.

However, by using the full path to `stat`, the command completes as expected in each version of both shells. An example that produces all times found with `stat` follows.

```
/usr/bin/stat -f "Access (atime): %Sa%nModify (mtime): %Sm%nChange (ctime): %Sc%nBirth  (Btime): %SB" testing.txt
```

The command produces output such as the following result from the command above.

```
Access (atime): Feb 21 10:46:41 2019
Modify (mtime): Feb 21 10:46:21 2019
Change (ctime): Feb 21 10:46:21 2019
Birth  (Btime): Feb 21 10:22:17 2019
```

This was an interesting question, and I hope to receive more insight on the cause of the disparity.

Comment: `zsh` has a `stat` builtin (predates both BSD `stat` and GNU `stat`), but it's not activated (in its default build) unless you run `zmodload zsh/stat` (maybe you have that in your `~/.zshrc`). Even then you can always run `command stat` instead of `stat` to get the OS's `stat`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes - the `stat` builtin was loaded! Thank you!

Comment: Now it works, thank you. The date I am looking for was "Change (ctime)". I'm also on 10.14.3 and I am using another language than English. The field literally translates to "Date Added" and if you google "Date Added Finder" you get a lot of results which show that field existing in the same place as my local translation of "Date Added". For example: http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/sort-files-by-date-modified-mac-finder-1.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ69g.png

Comment: @DisplayName I see. Thank you. Indeed, I do find "Date Added" in the column display options, but not from "Get Info."